# Change Bootstrap progress bar dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML code, using Bootstrap:

```
<div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want `style="width: 0"` to increase until it is 100%. I tried to use the code below as a test, but nothing happened.

```
<head>
    <title>Verifying Oracle database...</title>

    <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#progress-bar").css("width", "50%");
            $("#progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow", "50%");
        });

    </script>

</head>
```

Can someone help to make this progress happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are running that script before the DOM element is loaded. You need to either wrap it in `$(document).ready()` or put the script at the end of `<body>`

Comment: @Brennan, thanks for the answer. I put at the end of `<body>` but didn't work also. :(

Answer (score 15):

The code you use to update width is correct, but as @Brennan pointed out it has to run after the progress bar is rendered - e.g. by placing the script tag **after the progress bar tag** ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abaguinski/6gkzppta/3/)) or by running it in the document ready handler ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abaguinski/6gkzppta/2/)).

The following is the minimal version which does what you tried (the fiddles emulate progress running from 0 to 100):

```
$(function() {
     $("#progress-bar").css("width", "50%");
});
```

Another note on the code: along with the width of the progress bar you should update the [`aria-valuenow` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-valuenow) which represents the current value of a range widget (here the progress bar) for the assistive technology browsers. In your sample you have aria-valuenow 45 but width 0, which is inconsistent.

Comment: The new code should work. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Many thanks for a great progress bar. I have one minor modification and one comment: Instead of value +=10 I am using value = parseInt($("#targetPB").text(), 10) || 0; since I need publish the value in targetPB by an Ajax call and that may return with 'None' - which in turn will cause a NaN error - thus the parseInt and the  || 0...if not a number have a zero. The comment is that while the progress bar works nicely in Chrome and Firefox , it does not work in Safari (on Mac)